# decltype(auto) works with SFINAE in some cases?

Tags: c++, c++17, sfinae

I was under the assumption that `decltype(auto)` is an incompatible construct when used to try and SFINAE off the return type.  So, when you would have otherwise gotten a substitution error you get a hard error

But why does the following program work? https://wandbox.org/permlink/xyvxYsakTD1tM3yl

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

template <typename T>
class Identity {
public:
  using type = T;
};

template <typename T>
decltype(auto) construct(T&&) {
  return T{};
}

template <typename T, typename = std::void_t<>>
class Foo {
public:
  static void foo() {
    cout << "Nonspecialized foo called" << endl;
  }
};
template <typename T>
class Foo<T,
          std::void_t<typename decltype(construct(T{}))::type>> {
public:
  static void foo() {
    cout << "Specialized foo called" << endl;
  }
};

int main() {
  Foo<Identity<int>>::foo();
  Foo<int>::foo();
}
```

Shouldn't we get a hard error when `Foo` is instantiated with `int`?  Given that int has no member alias named `type`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I was under the assumption that `decltype(auto)` is an incompatible construct when used to try and SFINAE off the return type.

It is generally incompatible because it forces instantiation of the body of the function. If a substitution failure occurs in the *body*, then that's going to be a hard compile error - SFINAE doesn't apply here.

However, in this example, the only way that you would get a substitution failure in the body is if `T` weren't default constructible. But you call `construct(T{})`, which already requires `T` to be default constructible - so the failure would happen first or never.

Instead, the substitution failure that happens is in the immediate context of substituting into `typename decltype(construct(T{}))::type`. Trying to get `::type` off of an `int` happens while we're in the immediate context of instantiating the template arguments to `Foo`, so SFINAE still applies.

An example demonstrating where `decltype(auto)` breaks SFINAE is if we had instead implemented this as:

```
template <typename T>
decltype(auto) construct() {
  return T{};
}

template <typename T, typename = std::void_t<>>
class Foo {
public:
  static void foo() {
    cout << "Nonspecialized foo called" << endl;
  }
};
template <typename T>
class Foo<T,
          std::void_t<typename decltype(construct<T>())::type>> {
public:
  static void foo() {
    cout << "Specialized foo called" << endl;
  }
};
```

And then tried to instantiate:

```
struct X {
    X(int);
};

Foo<X>::foo(); // hard error, failure is in the body of construct()
```

Comment: Ah, that makes a lot of sense!  My understanding was incomplete apparently.  Thanks!  Just for completeness, could you point to the relevant part in the standard?

Comment: Somehow I still don't get an error here - https://wandbox.org/permlink/PsV9Z7mlCS8uzppg?

Comment: @Curious Because now the `T{}` is in the immediate context first.